# Site guest user problems to view lightning flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, force.com-sites, guest-user

I created a Lightning application to allow a visual flow to run with Lightning runtime. The problem is that when I run the force site as the guest user, the flow doesn't show correctly to the guest user:

[image]

But if I do a preview of the visualforce page from Salesforce, it looks ok:

[image]

What could be the reason to cause an incorrect visualization to the guest user?

**Component**:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
<aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>
```

**Visualforce page**

```
    <apex:page >
   <html>
      <head>
         <apex:includeLightning />
      </head>
      <body class="slds-scope">         
         <div id="flowContainer"/>
         <script>
            var statusChange = function (event) {
               if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {                
                  var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
                  var key;
                  for(key in outputVariables) {
                     if(outputVariables[key].name === "myOutput") {
                     }
                  }
               }
            };
            $Lightning.use("c:DLAflow", function() {
               $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange},
                  "flowContainer",
                  function (component) {                    
                     component.startFlow("DLA_Application_Page");
                  }
               );
            },);
         </script>
      </body>
   </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in showHeader="false" to your apex:page tag.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
```

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick :)